# How can I allow user put a website link into text_area and display the link that is clickable in Rails 4?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

And user can put a description of the party.
Also the user can type any link as description.

However, after user saved, the link he typed is not clickable.
I have to copy the link address and paste into browser to go to the site.

Below is the `views/parties/_form.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(@party, multipart: true) do |f| %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
      <ul><%= @party.errors.full_messages.first if @party.errors.any? %></ul>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :title, :class => "form-control", placeholder: 'Type title' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :location %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :location, :class => "form-control", placeholder: 'Type location' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>time</label>
        <%= f.datetime_select :time %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br>
    <a style="text-decoration:none;" title="Suggest!" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="hover" data-placement="top" data-content="Ticket? Any Link? Tell me more!"><%= f.text_area :description, :class => "form-control", :rows => "3" %></a>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :image %><br>
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
  </div>
  <p>
  </p>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Let's post it", :class => "btn btn-primary", :id => "load", 'data-loading-text' => "Uploading...".html_safe %>
  </div>
  <p>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

How can I convert the link to clickable link if user typed any link? when show its description?

```
For example, if a user typed,
"Hi we have party tomorrow at 12:00 pm.
Also more information is at www.facebook.com/samplepartybrabrabra
ticket is $5 per person."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Tl;dr** Use the the `auto_link` view helper from the [rails_autolink gem](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink).

---

**The long answer** You basically have two options:

1. The user has to enter a valid HTML link that can then be rendered as HTML as Anthony suggests. You can make this easier for the user by using markdown or a wysiwyg editor.
2. You let the user enter just an URL in the text (that's what you're doing right now) and you have to parse the text and replace every URL with a HTML link.

Personally, I'd go with option #2, especially since it's quite easy with the [rails_autolink gem](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink). You can leave your form as is. And all you have to to is print the user input later with:

```html
<div class="party-description">
  <%= auto_link(@party.description) %>
</div>
```

and `auto_link` will take care of all the links.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `variable_name.html_safe` to allow text in `variable_name` to be interpreted and rendered as HTML. Just be sure to do so with caution if `variable_name` is derived from user-generated content.

Comment: in the views/parties/show.html.erb
`@party.description.html_safe` not working.. still not clickable.